# Javascript, load onclick at pageload, whats broken?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a dizzy designer. I can't can't see why this isn't working:

```
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $().ready(function() {
           $('#test').trigger("click");
      });
 </script>  
 </head>
 <body>
      <a id="test" href="http://www.dartworks.net" >click here</a>
</body>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: To make your question clear, please explain what you are expecting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't attach any click event to the `<a>` tag you just output it as a link

use the window.location.href like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.dartworks.net";
});
```

Comment: Awesome. The missing click event has been added and is working. The window.location.href method works for a page redirect. My end goal for this code needs the click event. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The trigger method will fire all the event handlers bound to that event. Following the link is default behaviour, not something caused by a DOM event handler.